# how to show single quote in single-quoted text

Tags: bash, echo, double-quotes, quotation-marks

I have a `bash` script,

```
echo 'abcd'
```

in shell, I want to show `ab'c'd` and I have tried following approach but without success

```
echo 'ab\'c\'d'
```

I am asking is it possible to show single quote in single quoted text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `bash` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) section on [Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

You'll need to use double quotes instead.  It's not pretty, but the following gives the output you are looking for:

```
echo 'ab'"'"'c'"'"'d'
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash-specific feature, not part of POSIX, is a `$'...'`-quoted string:

```
echo $'ab\'c\'d'
```

Such a string behaves identically to a single-quoted string, but does allow for a selection of \-escaped characters (such as \n, \t, and yes, \').